# Typescript - Parameter 'u' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: typescript, angular

I converted this code to the latest Angular 2.  [authentication.service.ts](https://github.com/leonardohjines/angular2-login/blob/master/app/authentication.service.ts)

What should the code look like?

```
app/auth/auth.service.ts(30,40): error TS7006: Parameter 'u' implicitly has an 'any' type.

// services/auth.service.ts
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

//http://4dev.tech/2016/03/login-screen-and-authentication-with-angular2/
//https://github.com/leonardohjines/angular2-login
export class User {
  constructor(
    public email: string,
    public password: string) { }
}

var users:any = [
  new User('admin@admin.com','adm9'),
  new User('user1@gmail.com','a23')
];

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

  constructor(
    private _router: Router){}

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem("user");
    this._router.navigate(['Login']);
  }

  login(user:any){
    var authenticatedUser = users.find(u => u.email === user.email);
    if (authenticatedUser){
      localStorage.setItem("user", authenticatedUser);
      this._router.navigate(['Home']);      
      return true;
    }
    return false;

  }

   checkCredentials( ){
    if (localStorage.getItem("user") === null){
        this._router.navigate(['Login']);
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Have you seen a fix for this error?

Answer (score 14):

Consider using  (u: any) => ...

Answer (score 11):

You could try to use the `User` type instead of `any`:

```
var users:User[] = [
  (...)
];
```

and

```
var authenticatedUser = users.find((u:User) => u.email === user.email);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason of problem is a parameter that is not properly defined, as this case is the variable "u" following the example:

```
var authenticatedUser = users.find(u => u.email === user.email);
```

if you dont have the class model of service, should be defined "u" as string or other type what you need in the moment:

```
var authenticatedUser = users.find(u:string => u.email === user.email);
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm using the same example you have used.

Instead of apply any, set the parameter type to `User`.

So, your login method would be something like this:

`login(user: User): boolean { ...`

Then, remove any reference to `any` key word.

Answer (score 0):

2 changes to make:

- in `tsconfig.json` file: `"noImplicitAny": false,`
- in `systemjs.config.js`, add:

  `'ng2-formly': 'npm:ng2-formly/bundles/ng2-formly.umd.js',`

Comment: The `"noImplicitAny": false` in tsconfig.json just saved me!